# Is the Maven Dependency Graph feature of IntelliJ available in Community Edition?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/

I can't find it, and I wonder if it's because I'm lame, or because it's only available in Ultimate.

Comment: In case you are working with the Ultimate Edition and you still do not see the dependency graph menu item: make sure that the following plugins are activated: Maven Integration, Maven Integration Extension, UML Support. In particular the last one is important - I had it deactivated and searched an hour to find out that it is necessary for the dependency graph to work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is available only in the Ultimate Edition. (Right click your maven module in the `Maven Projects` tab and select `Show Dependencies(?: Popup)?.` from the context menu.

Answer (score 39):

If you have an Ultimate Edition and you still can't see the "Show Dependencies"/"Show Dependencies popup" then its most probably because the UML Plugin is disabled. I just faced this issue and poured over many different forums to find the cause..!

Comment: It is called, is called UML Support and is bundled in IDEA (using 13 now).  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_designer.html.  Needed to enable as a built-in plugin and restart IDEA.

Comment: Still true for IDEA 2016, Settings > Plugins > UML Support ✓

Answer (score 8):

There is something better now, [Maven Helper plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179).

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/mavenprojecthelper/ is old now last updated 8/2008.  UML Support in Ultimate Edition seems to work.  See other answer here (at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21920977/1041319)

Comment: That is a different plugin, how did you came up with that is incomprehensible.

Comment: Nice suggestion !

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in `pom.xml` editor
(ultimate edition with UML plugin  enabled)

Answer (score 2):

If using the Ultimate Edition, make sure the following plugins are enabled:

- Maven Integration Extensions
- UML Support

They are both required (in 15 anyway) to see the dependency diagram.